# Option to Narrow Google Pay Checkout Window width to reveal PAY button?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, google-pay, google-checkout

Google Pay checkout window (pay.google.com) has a minimum width of 608px. The default minimum width of the Google browser (at least on Windows) is 500px and it be even narrower in some instances. As a result, when the Google Checkout window pops up and the browser width is 500px for example, the "Pay" button is hidden and the user cannot checkout unless they know to widen the browser to reveal the button. While we are using the Stripe API for checkout, I believe the final checkout window referenced belongs to Google.

[image]

Am I missing an option somewhere?

Thanks in advance for any direction.

Comment: Just an FYI: The text you have blurred can be restored. You probably want to slimply put an opaque block over them rather than blurring them.

Comment: @starball - Yikes! I tried to see what you were saying but I was unable to restore it. You were able to? If so, pls let me know and I will replace them. Thank you!!! :-)

Comment: No I didn't try it, but I know it can be done and I've seen people use tools to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, yes that modal is controlled/rendered by Google. You could try contacting their support team to see if there are any workarounds.

Fwiw, I don't see the same behaviour on my machine. Refer to the screenshot attached. Modal keeps the original width regardless of if I resize the browser before the modal is rendered OR afterwards.[image]

Comment: wow - that's weird. I went to the same Stripe docs page that you have pictured on all Chrome versions (stable, beta, dev and canary) and I still had my same issue... Thank you for your info though - I will continue to pursue this.